# HowTo Install the Django emailauth App into a New Project

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls, django-apps

I'm a Django newbie and am interesting in understanding how to install the EmailAuth app into my new project:

http://github.com/redvasily/django-emailauth

Seems like Django apps are meant to be plug in play so I must be missing something....

Here's what I tried.
I created a new project
copied the emailauth directory over
Updated my settings.py with the INSTALLED_APPS 'emailauth' and made sure my settings.py had correct db and email settings.

But that failed, I must be missing some other installation requirements?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django apps are [Python modules](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html).

Comment: Thanks. I was able to install the app/module. The problem is now that app is hidden from my project folder and I want to be able to customize the templates, login, registration screens etc. How does Django support that?